# compilation errors in Java while typecasting

Tags: java

While I am trying to do typecasting with my function return value, I get compilation errors in Java

```
 public  short subtractNumbers (short a, byte b, float k )
 {
       short result=short(a+b-k);
       return result;
 }
```

For the above-written code snippet, I get the error statements from compiler, as:

```
 error: '.class' expected
  short result=short(a+b-k);
                    ^
  error: not a statement
  short result=short(a+b-k);
                     ^
  error: ';' expected
  short result=short(a+b-k);
                      ^
```

What could be the problem here, and what is the logic behind the error statements ?
Thanks in advance for the help, I would be really appreciated.

Comment: you might be out for `(short)(a+b-k)`?

Comment: Its `short result=(short)(a+b-k);` since `short` is a datatype. not method to pass a value to it.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get the suggestion of you

Comment: The suggestions show *exactly* the code you need. Basically you've got the wrong syntax for casting...

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Satya

Answer (score 6):

That's not the syntax for type-casting. The correct syntax is

```
short s = (short) someValue;
```

and not

```
short s = short(someValue);
```

So you want

```
short result = (short) (a + b - k);
```

Comment: If OP wonders why he needs to wrap `a + b - k` with parenthese: because `(short) a + b - k` would only cast `a` to short, not the result of the calculation.

Comment: How about `short s = new short(someValue);` ? (i'm not that used to Java)

Comment: @TobiasR. what does your compiler say about that line of code? Is short a class? Can you use new on primitive types?

Comment: @TobiasR. there is no `new short()` or generally `new` for primitives, you could just use the wrapper class `Short`, which either needs a `String` or a `short` as parameter. Therefore you would have more unnecessery code, since `a+b-k` had to be either cast to a `String`, or would still need the `short` cast.

Comment: Oh.. true.. I always forget about that "primitivs are 'special' " thing in Java.. Ty for answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer